# Angular - Data is loaded after template is rendered - router.navigate from a custom error handler

Tags: angular, typescript

I have built a custom error handler class to intercept all the errors that happen in the app. When an error happens, the app redirects the user to an error view using router.navigate and sending the error details as query parameters. The component simply reads the query parameters and bind them in the view. Although i can see that the query parameter variable has data in the developer console, it is not being displayed in the view. I need to refresh the error page to see that data in the view.

I decided to hard-coded the variable value that i want to display in the view in the constructor and/or in the ngOnInit methods, in order to see if the variable is displayed in the view, and i still cannot see the value when the page is being loaded from the handler using the router.navigate. If i type the error URL directly i can indeed see the value binded.

I am wondering if the issue has something to do that the this._router.navigate is being triggered from a custom error handler.

I appreciate any help?

Error handler Class:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorsHandler implements ErrorHandler {
 constructor(
     private injector: Injector,
 ) {}

handleError(error: Error | HttpErrorResponse) {        

  const router = this.injector.get(Router);
  const appService = this.injector.get(AppService);

  router.navigate(['/error'], { queryParams: {error: error} }); 

  }
}
```

Component:

```
export class ErrorsComponent implements OnInit {

      errorMessage: any;
      constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private _appService: AppService) {

        // activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(
        //   params => {
        //     this.errorMessage = params;
        //     console.log(this.errorMessage.error);

        //   });

        this.errorMessage = 'Hi';
        console.log(this.errorMessage);

      }

      ngOnInit() {

      }
    }
```

Template:

```
    <div class="error-container">
      <div>
        <h1 *ngIf="errorMessage" >ERROR {{errorMessage}}</h1>
        <a mat-raised-button [routerLink]="'/'">
          <h5>Get a new Candiate</h5>
        </a>
      </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: Don't know if it's would help, but, I set and get router parameter in another way. The main thing, which may impact - is to use subscribe for getting router parameter and save it to you component variable. I had have the same problem and it was resolved it for me.

Comment: well, as u can see in the code i tried with "subscribe" and it didn't work. Even worse, the example u can see in the code has the value i want to display hardcoded, i am not event reading the query params anymore. I am wondering if ity has something to do that the this._router.navigate is being triggered from a custom error handler.

Comment: Why do you want to pass the error as URL parameter? Store it in the error handler and inject that into the `ErrorsComponent` where you can read the error.

Comment: Store it? U mean using a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when an exception is triggered it makes the app leaves the angular zone, this is by design. The solution is to redirect to the error page using the run method of the service NgZone , forcing to reenter the Angular zone as follows:

```
this._zone.run(() => router.navigate(['/error'], { queryParams: {error: error} }));
```

Import the module:

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 0):

Component from which we redirect:

```
moveToErrorView(myError: string) {
this._router.navigate(['app/error-view', myError]);
}
```

Component error-view(get the parameter):

```
sub: any;
...
constructor(praivate _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
};
...
ngOnInit() {
this.sub = this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
this.redirectedError = params['myError'];
});
```

and then use the redirectedError variable to bind it to HTML view as {{redirectedError}}

Comment: well, as u can see in the code i tried with "subscribe" and it didn't work. Even worse, the example u can see in the code has the value i want to display hardcoded, i am not event reading the query params anymore. I am wondering if ity has something to do that the this._router.navigate is being triggered from a custom error handler.